# Transmission on Scion slow to shift out of second gear, but only once

Tags: automatic-transmission, scion

I have looked through the questions recommended by SO and none of them seem to address this specific issue - and it's the only one the car has, otherwise it's in immaculate condition.

It is a 2007 Scion with automatic transmission.  In the morning when I drive it, I've just gotten used to the fact that it will only go to second gear for about the first 60 seconds of driving.  No problem, I live in a suburban area, just go slowly around 30MPH and eventually it will shift into higher gear.  Possibly, *maybe*, a bit longer on a cold day but not much.

My suspicion is that there is a gummed-up something that releases as soon as the transmission is warm.

My question(s) are, what is the likely problem, is it likely to get worse, and is there any non-invasive approach (like additives) that would be a good first try in order to resolve it?  Thanks!

Comment: Some years ago I had the use of an automatic Audi for a time. It would not shift into top gear until the engine had warmed up a bit. I thought it was a design feature to stop it labouring when cold, but it was annoying. The owner told me it had been like that from new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this complaint recently on this site.  Turns out, Toyota designs many models [to stay in low gear purposefully](https://www.toyotanation.com/threads/cold-engine-light-sluggish-upshift-help.873410/) in cold weather to warm-up the transmission.  It's perfectly normal and will not get worse.

Comment: that's unusual, I'm fine with it. Thanks for the link.  But my only wry observation is, this is Texas where it's 100 degrees in the summer ;)

Comment: @Oliver Williams - Upon rereading your original post, I see you have the problem for only the first 60 seconds of driving.  People who live in cold climates have it for several minutes.